# Django programming error relation does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

Everything appears to run smoothly in my app until I try to access these models from the admin site, that's when I'm getting the error I mentioned, I have Allauth installed and have made all necessary migrations but I keep getting the same error no matter what I do.

Any ideas?

Here are the models:

```
class Cuentas(models.Model):
    idCuenta = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=15)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    Saldo = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cuentas'

class Depositos(models.Model):
    idDeposito = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=15)
    idCuenta = models.ForeignKey(Cuentas)
    Tipo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Monto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Fecha = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'deposits'
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  583.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  206.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1485.                 self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in __init__
  110.         self.get_results(request)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in get_results
  219.         result_count = paginator.count
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in _get_count
  72.                 self._count = self.object_list.count()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  338.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  436.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using=using)[None]
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  402.         result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  786.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/DraftFantasy/cuentas/
Exception Value: relation "cuentas" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cuentas"
```

This is the code inside the initial migration which creates both models

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Cuentas',
        fields=[
            ('idCuenta', models.AutoField(max_length=15, serialize=False, primary_key=True)),
            ('Saldo', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('user', models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
        options={
        },
        bases=(models.Model,),
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Depositos',
        fields=[
            ('idDeposito', models.AutoField(max_length=15, serialize=False, primary_key=True)),
            ('Tipo', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ('Monto', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ('Fecha', models.DateField()),
            ('idCuenta', models.ForeignKey(to='DraftFantasy.Cuentas')),
        ],
        options={
        },
        bases=(models.Model,),
    ),
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can i see the full traceback ?

Comment: If you have `managed = False`, then Django will not create any migrations for these models, and you will have to create them yourself.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the full traceback, also as I mentioned I've created and run all necessary migrations

Comment: Are you certain that you have a migratin that creates the models? As I said before, Django will not create migrations for models that have `managed=False`. Please show the migration that you think creates the models, and the output of `./manage.py showmigrations`.

Comment: I've added the code from the initial migration which creates the models

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether this is the same problem, but I fix my own similar issue just by catching this `ProgrammingError` exception - take a look [here](https://github.com/SpisTresci/SpisTresci/pull/38/files#diff-ba3d608cdaa89d4feb35554dea4cb724R23).

From what I know from investigation, it seems that configuration from admin.py is loaded even before you will run `python manage.py migrate` first time. This can be tricky during development, because you can not notice this problem if you will first create a model, migrate it locally and later develop some changes in admin.py which depends on new model.

So make sure, that your admin.py files do not depends on models, or can **survive first run before database is migrated**.